# Post method cannot pass to view function

Tags: django

I fill in the form but get an empty result.

- The new_entry page:

[image]

- The page it redirect(which intend to return the new entry.
  [image]

The new_entry function in views.py

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted, create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
        print("get") # test point
    else:
        # POST data submittd; process data
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        print('Post') # test point
        # print('request: ', request)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic':topic, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context )
```

It print 'get' on the console

```
    Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    this is get method
    [11/May/2018 02:26:48] "GET /new_entry/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 461
```

Request method is "POST" in "new_entry.html"

```
    {% block content %}
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
        </p>
        <p>Add a new entry:</p>
        <form  action="{% url "learning_logs:topic" topic.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button name="button">add entry</button>

        </form>

    {% endblock content %}
```

The topics.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topics</p>

<ul>
    {% for topic in topics  %}
        <a href="{% url "learning_logs:topic" topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a> <br>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url "learning_logs:new_topic" %}">Add a new topic:</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

The form.py was doublechecked

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text':''}

    class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Entry
            fields = ['text']
            labels = {'text':''}
            widgets = {'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80})}
```

The urls pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home Page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # Show all the topics
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail pate for a single topics
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    # Page for adding a new topic
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    # page for adding a new new Entry
    url(r"^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)$", views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),

]
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: what you get when it's `request.POST` ? when you submit

Comment: Maybe the issue is not in this view, can you add the other view (`topic()`), the `urls patterns` and its template

Comment: add the other view (topic()), the urls patterns and its template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you did not submit to the view that supposes to receive the POST request, look

```
<form  action="{% url "learning_logs:topic" topic.id %}" method="POST">
```

With this you post to the view `topic` with the topic ID.

Instead, it should be

```
<form  action="{% url "learning_logs:new_entry" topic.id %}" method="POST">
```